# Vaadin Horizontal Layout not aligning well

Tags: layout, vaadin

I am trying to create a horizontal layout of TextField added to a Panel, but its aligned vertically.

See my code below;

```
    HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    TextField txtUsername = new TextField("Username");
    txtUsername.setRequired(true);
    horizontalLayout.addComponent(txtUsername);

    PasswordField txtPassword = new PasswordField("Password");
    txtPassword.setRequired(true);
    horizontalLayout.addComponent(txtPassword);

    horizontalLayout.setStyleName("formLayout");

    VerticalLayout panelLayout = new VerticalLayout(horizontalLayout);
    setContent(panelLayout);
```

[image: This is what I get ...]

Comment: Code seems to be fine. Try setting the horizontal layout directly as content of panel (for testing).

Comment: What is the CSS of "formLayout" style?

Comment: `FormLayout` is also a Vaadin layout. That particular style name may interfere with your horizontal layout. Other than that all seems fine.

Comment: I am trying to mix both the vertical layout and horizontal layout, so i have two other form element vertically, and adding a horizontal layout  for the form.

Comment: Just tried using the horizontal layout as the content of the panel ... still the same ..

Comment: Are you sure your changes are taking effect?

Comment: Yes ... had to remove all the component on the UI, and add the form alone ... still the same result ...

Comment: Please provide CSS of "formLayout".

Comment: GridLayout may help, too.

Comment: Any progress on that topic?